# Amazon cognito identify js issue

Tags: random

Sorry, I need to take delete this, but I cannot delete the post.

https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/98

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cognito you have to be authenticated in order to change passwords. If you don't know the password and thus can't authenticate then you need to use forgotPassword.

In your code where you have "but i cannot do that because of the lib" what error are you getting?

Note that the authenticateUser function does not take the normal (err, result) style callback as the second parameter. It takes an object that contains onSuccess/onFailure/mfaRequired/newPasswordRequired named functions. Which of those functions gets triggered by your call to authenticateUser?